# Is it possible to run 2 separate INSERT statements in one?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

First, I am a security guy, not a developer.  If there is an easier way to do what I am trying to do, I wouldn't be surprised.  This is my first time doing anything in C# so be gentle.

I am working on a database to track our compliance with audit controls.  The database is MS SQL 2008 with a web app front end that I am writing in C#.  I am working on a page that allows a user to update the control with test results or change the requirements or pretty much anything else.  When the information is updated on this page, I am trying to write the existing data from the Controls table to the History table before updating the record in the Controls table.  I am also trying to log (in the `History` table) who made the update and when.  This is where I am running into a problem.  I can nest a `SELECT` statement in the `INSERT` statement to pull the data over, but I cannot figure out how to add date and time it was updated and the user that updated it.

This is my query currently that doesn't work for obvious reasons.  Just so you have an idea of what columns and parameters I am working with.

```
INSERT INTO History (BUName, ControlFWName, ControlID, ControlDesc, 
                     TestPlan, TestFreq, NextTest, ControlCatName,
                     AuditorNotes, AuditorNoteTime, TestResults, ArtifactID1, 
                     ArtifactID2, ArtifactID3, ArtifactID4, 
                     WhoChanged, WhenChanged) 
                     SELECT BUName, ControlFWName, ControlID, ControlDesc, 
                            TestPlan, TestFreq, NextTest, ControlCatName, 
                            AuditorNotes, AuditorNoteTime, TestResults, ArtifactID1, 
                            ArtifactID2, ArtifactID3, ArtifactID4 
                     FROM Controls 
                     WHERE BUName = @BUName 
                       AND ControlFWName = @ControlFWName 
                       AND ControlID = @ControlID
```

How do I append the `WhoChanged` and `WhenChanged` columns to that insert statement?  They are parameterized to variables that are just `DateTime.Now` and `User.Identity.Name`.

If you need more code, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a couple of different routes you could go. You can either solve the problem with stored procedures or triggers.

Stored procedures give you a lot of control. You can accept whatever parameters you want and run a series of INSERT and UPDATE statements, etc. And it puts all your code in one, nicely archived place. Don't forget inline comments too.

The big advantage of triggers is that the always run. Is there any chance that one of your colleagues would access the data tables and modify data? If your app uses stored procedures, the history table and controls table could fall out of sync. Is that a problem?

(As an aside, I would consider adding the WhoChanged and WhenChanged to your controls table. Then you can simply write the entire Controls row into the History table before you modify it. That can be done with either the trigger or stored procedure.

**EDIT**

To be clear, when are you creating the History records? Are you creating them on each INSERT and UPDATE? Just want to make sure that each record is flagged with the ID/timestamp that created that data. If you are only moving data to the History table when it is obsoleted, then you are marking it with info about who and when it was deleted. This could be confusing to those that come after.

Comment: I had considered adding the columns to the Controls table, but I was trying to stay away from it.  I have been reading about computed columns in SQL Server.  Would it be possible to just have SQL server capture the timestamp and username when a record is added instead?

Comment: It is certainly possible, as long as you are using Trusted Authentication for the data connection and all your Kerberos stuff is configurated appropriately. Often web apps run in the context of a service account so you don't have to give database rights to the users. Up to you. There are at least 4 different "current user" functions in SQL, and I don't remember which one is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

> This is my first time doing anything in C# so be gentle.

But this is a T-SQL  and not a C# question, isn't it?

You just have to add the parameters to the query:

```
INSERT INTO history 
            (buname, controlfwname,  controlid, controldesc, 
             testplan, testfreq, nexttest, controlcatname, 
             auditornotes, auditornotetime, testresults, 
             artifactid1, artifactid2, artifactid3, artifactid4, 
             whochanged, whenchanged) 
SELECT buname, controlfwname, controlid, controldesc, 
       testplan, testfreq, nexttest, controlcatname, 
       auditornotes, auditornotetime, testresults, 
       artifactid1, artifactid2, artifactid3, artifactid4, 
       @WhoChanged, @WhenChanged 
FROM   controls 
WHERE  buname = @BUName 
       AND controlfwname = @ControlFWName 
       AND controlid = @ControlID
```

Here the C# part although it's not clear why it could be important:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO history 
             (buname, controlfwname,  controlid, controldesc, 
             testplan, testfreq, nexttest, controlcatname, 
             auditornotes, auditornotetime, testresults, 
             artifactid1, artifactid2, artifactid3, artifactid4, 
             whochanged, whenchanged) 
SELECT buname, controlfwname, controlid, controldesc, 
       testplan, testfreq, nexttest, controlcatname, 
       auditornotes, auditornotetime, testresults, 
       artifactid1, artifactid2, artifactid3, artifactid4, 
       @WhoChanged, @WhenChanged 
FROM   controls 
WHERE  buname = @BUName 
       AND controlfwname = @ControlFWName 
       AND controlid = @ControlID";

// use the using statement to ensure that unmanaged resources are disposed and the connection is closed
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string user = HttpRequest.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhoChanged", user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhenChanged", now);
    // ...
    con.Open();
    int affectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's my first development project of any sort really, but yes, my problem is more SQL than C#.

I tried adding the parameters to the query but those columns don't exist in the Controls table so it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2391629: So `whochanged, whenchanged` are not columns in the `controls` table? Then i don't understand the problem/requirement. Just remove them from the sql.

Comment: I needed to capture that information though for audit purposes.  I went ahead and added them to the Control table and got it working.  I think I was over-complicating it.  Thanks for the help.